# Keras shows no Improvements to training speed with GPU (partial GPU usage?!)

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to train my model on a GPU instead of a CPU on an AWS p2.xlarge instance from my Jupyter Notebook. I am using tensorflow-gpu backend (only `tensorflow-gpu` was installed and mentioned in `requirements.txt` and not `tensorflow`).

I am not seeing any speed improvements when training models on these instances compared to using a CPU, infact I am getting training speeds per epoch that is almost same as I am getting on my 4-core  laptop CPU (p2.xlarge also has 4 vCPUs with a Tesla K80 GPU). I am not sure if i need to do some changes to my code to accommodate faster/parallel processing that GPU can offer. I am pasting below my code for my model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(recurrent.LSTM(64, input_shape=(X_np.shape[1], X_np.shape[2]),
                        return_sequences=True))
model.add(recurrent.LSTM(64, return_sequences = False))
model.add(core.Dropout(0.1))
model.add(core.Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_np, y_np, epochs=100, validation_split=0.25)
```

Also interestingly the GPU seems to be utilizing between 50%-60% of its processing power and almost all of its memory every time I check for GPU status using `nvidia-smi` (but both fall to 0% and 1MiB respectively when not training):

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 384.81                 Driver Version: 384.81                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla K80           On   | 00000000:00:1E.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   47C    P0    73W / 149W |  10919MiB / 11439MiB |     52%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1665      C   ...ubuntu/aDash/MLenv/bin/python 10906MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Also if you'd like to see my logs about using the GPU from Jupyter Notebook:

```
[I 04:21:59.390 NotebookApp] Kernel started: c17bc4d1-fa15-4b0e-b5f0-87f90e56bf65
[I 04:22:02.241 NotebookApp] Adapting to protocol v5.1 for kernel c17bc4d1-fa15-4b0e-b5f0-87f90e56bf65
2017-11-30 04:22:32.403981: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
2017-11-30 04:22:33.653681: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:892] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2017-11-30 04:22:33.654041: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1030] Found device 0 with properties:
name: Tesla K80 major: 3 minor: 7 memoryClockRate(GHz): 0.8235
pciBusID: 0000:00:1e.0
totalMemory: 11.17GiB freeMemory: 11.10GiB
2017-11-30 04:22:33.654070: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1120] Creating TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0) -> (device: 0, name: Tesla K80, pci bus id: 0000:00:1e.0, compute capability: 3.7)
2017-11-30 04:22:34.014329: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1120] Creating TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0) -> (device: 0, name: Tesla K80, pci bus id: 0000:00:1e.0, compute capability: 3.7)
Device mapping:
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 -> device: 0, name: Tesla K80, pci bus id: 0000:00:1e.0, compute capability: 3.7
2017-11-30 04:22:34.015339: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc:299] Device mapping:
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 -> device: 0, name: Tesla K80, pci bus id: 0000:00:1e.0, compute capability: 3.7

2017-11-30 04:23:22.426895: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1120] Creating TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0) -> (device: 0, name: Tesla K80, pci bus id: 0000:00:1e.0, compute capability: 3.7)
```

Please suggest what could be the problem. Thanks a ton for looking at this anyways!

Comment: Can you post your CPU usage as well? It may be that your bottleneck is the part that feeds data into your model.

Comment: What is the size of your dataset (shape of X_np and y_np)?

Comment: @AbderrahimKitouni 34000x7x5 (samples x timesteps x features) for input and target of 34000x1

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That happens because you're using LSTM layers.

Tensorflow's implementation for LSTM layers is not that great. The reason is probably that recurrent calculations are not parallel calculations, and GPUs are great for parallel processing.

I confirmed that by my own experience:

- Got terrible speed using LSTMs in my model
- Decided to test the model removing all LSTMs (got a pure convolutional model)
- The resulting speed was simply astonishing!!!

This article about using GPUs and tensorflow also confirms that:

- http://minimaxir.com/2017/07/cpu-or-gpu/

#### A possible solution?

You may try using the new [CuDNNLSTM](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#cudnnlstm), which seems prepared specially for using GPUs.

I never tested it, but you'll most probably get a better performance with this.

Another thing that I haven't tested, and I'm not sure it's designed for that reason, but I suspect it is: you can put `unroll=True` in your LSTM layers. With that, I suspect the recurrent calculations will be transformed in parallel ones.

Comment: I had not gone through the keras docs for a while and checked out cudnn layers were added in october. I did a test drive on my data and saw training per epoch cut to a third without doing any other changes. Will check this out more in a day or two.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use some bigger value for `batch_size` in `model.fit`, because the default is `32`. Increase it until you get 100% CPU utilization.

Following suggestion from @dgumo, you can also put your data into `/run/shm`. This is an in-memory file system, which allows to access data in fastest possible way. Alternatively, you can ensure that your data resides at least on SSD. For example in `/tmp`.

Comment: Agreed. LSTM is slow to train, but increasing the batch size should help a lot. You could also try other types of recurrent layers, like the GRU or the newly released [SRU](https://github.com/titu1994/keras-SRU)

Answer (score 0):

The bottleneck in your case is transferring data to and from the GPU. The best way to speed up your computation (and maximize your GPU usage) is to load as much of your data as your memory can hold at once. Since you have plenty of memory, you can put all your data at once, by doing:

```
model.fit(X_np, y_np, epochs=100, validation_split=0.25, batch_size=X_np.shape[0])
```

(You should also probably increase the number of epochs when doing this).

Note however that there are advantages to minibatching (e.g. better handling of local minima), so you should probably consider choosing a batch_size somewhere in between.